# Network with Windows 10 Computers

Tags: networking, windows

When I want to network with my window 10 network it asks for my user name etc., but whatever put in here it will not connect. Any suggestions?

Garry

Answer (score 0):

Check the advanced sharing settings in windows.  check to see if you have selected to use password protection sharing.  if it is enabled it will ask for user / password.  if you turn off password protection you should be able to access the windows system from ubuntu. Also check your sharing settings settings for the files / directories you want to share on the windows system.  I have found that if you use everyone I have not had issues accessing windows files thru ubuntu.  This is all based on using a local network without a domain.